# nodejs fibers not working for me

Tags: node.js, node-fibers

The `result` is populated in the `exec` function, but it never gets back to the main thread... what am I doing wrong?

```
  var Fiber, exec, execSync;

  exec = require("child_process").exec;

  Fiber = require('fibers');

  execSync = function(cmd) {
    var cmdExec, final;
    cmdExec = function(cmd) {
      var fiber,
        _this = this;
      fiber = Fiber.current;
      exec(cmd, function(se, so, e) {
        var result;
        fiber.run();
        result = se + so + e;
        return result;
      });
      return Fiber["yield"]();
    };
    final = '';
    Fiber(function() {
      return cmdExec(cmd);
    }).run();
    return final;
  };

  console.log(execSync('ls ..'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a few problems in that code.. Here's some code that does what you want:

```
var Fiber, exec, execSync;

exec = require("child_process").exec;

Fiber = require('fibers');

execSync = function(cmd) {
  var fiber = Fiber.current;
  exec(cmd, function(err, so, se) { 
    if (err) fiber.throwInto(err);
    fiber.run(se + so);
  });
  return Fiber.yield();
};

Fiber(function() {
  console.log(execSync('ls ..'));
}).run();
```

The big problem is that you seem to be mixing up the role of `run` and `yield`. Basically `yield` suspends a Fiber and `run` will resume (or start it for the first time). What you should be doing is running any code that needs to call `execSync` inside a Fiber, and then `execSync` will grab a reference to the current fiber and then call `Fiber.yield()`. When the `exec` call returns the fiber is resumed with `fiber.run()`.

The other smaller issue is some confused parameters to the callback for `exec`. The parameters are `err, stdout, stderr`.